# pygresql - insert and return serial

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql

I'm using [PyGreSQL](http://www.pygresql.org/pg.html) to access my DB. In the use-case I'm currently working on; I am trying to insert a record into a table and return the last rowid... aka the value that the DB created for my ID field:

```
create table job_runners (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    hostname     varchar(100) not null,
    is_available boolean default FALSE
    );

sql = "insert into job_runners (hostname) values ('localhost')"
```

When I used the db.insert(), which made the most sense, I received an "AttributeError". And when I tried db.query(sql) I get nothing but an OID.

Q: Using PyGreSQL what is the best way to insert records and return the value of the ID field without doing any additional reads or queries?

Comment: Please provide more info: the actual call to db.insert()/db.query(), exact error message, versions of both Postgres and PyGreSQL, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in PyGreSQL says that if you call dbconn.query() with and insert/update statement that it will return the OID. It goes on to say something about lists of OIDs when there are multiple rows involved.

First of all; I found that the OID features did not work. I suppose knowing the version numbers of the libs and tools would have helped, however, I was not trying to return the OID.

Finally; by appending "returning id", as suggested by @hacker, pygresql simply did the right thing and returned a record-set with the ID in the resulting dictionary (see code below).

```
sql = "insert into job_runners (hostname) values ('localhost') returning id"
rv = dbconn.query(sql)
id = rv.dictresult()[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO job_runners
    (hostname,is_available) VALUES ('localhost',true)
    RETURNING id
```

That said, I have no idea about pygresql, but by what you've already written, I guess it's `db.query()` that you want to use here.

Comment: @hacker - while the SQL above helped my issue was specifically with pygresql and getting that ID back from the DB.

Comment: Getting ID back from DB is in `RETURNING` part. I assumed you know how to get result that `db.query()` yields. Without that bit it won't hand generated id back to client.

Comment: Just read your own answer to your own question ;-) The OID thing isn't very good approach, because you do not always have OIDs, I don't think that `INSERT` is ever returning multiple OIDs (but I'm not sure, because I never used it) and finally you will still have to infer the `id` from OID. Which would be then easier to do by `SELECT`ing `currval('job_runners_id_seq')`.

Comment: @hacker - PERL's DBI class offers a method/attribute 'last_insert_id'. This is not the same as "returning".  Reading the doc explains that returning is analogous to 'select'. Thanks for pointing me in a direction that answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a cursor object `cur`:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO job_runners (hostname) VALUES (%(hostname)s) RETURNING id",
            {'hostname': 'localhost'})
id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

This ensures PyGreSQL correctly escapes the input string, preventing SQL injection.